# UML diagram for data feeds

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram, datafeed

I want to document data feeds from an application.  I'm thinking about a simple sequence diagram with two system boxes on top and an arrow representing each outgoing data feed

What is the best UML diagram for this?

Comment: Do you want to model the existence of the data feeds, or go down to the granularity of the format of the data feeds?

Comment: Good question. I do want to capture both. It would allow be to drill down to the details, when required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both a sequence diagram and a collaboration diagram. 
In the collaboration diagram you can show the simple interaction between the components (which messages are sent between them).
If you want go into more detail on the ordering of the messages and time constraints you can use a sequence diagram